# Testing forked redux-sagas with redux-saga-test-plan

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, redux-saga

I am trying to test my redux-sagas with the redux-saga-test-plan library to make things easier. All tests are run in a JEST environment.

To help me structure my tests on a forked saga I followed the documentation here: https://github.com/jfairbank/redux-saga-test-plan/blob/master/docs/integration-testing/forked-sagas.md

But when I try to run the test i get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

  12 |   .put(setMenu(menuList))
  13 |   .dispatch('SET_MENU_REQUEST', menuList)
> 14 |   .run()
  15 | })
  16 |
```

**My test (updated):**

```
import { expectSaga } from 'redux-saga-test-plan'
import { call, put, takeLatest, takeEvery } from "redux-saga/effects";
import menuSaga from '../../sagas/MenuSaga'
import { applyMenu } from '../../sagas/MenuSaga'
import { menuList } from '../../stubs/menuList'
import { setMenu } from '../../reducers/menuReducer'

it("Sets a new menu", () => {

  return expectSaga(applyMenu)
  .put(setMenu(menuList))
  .dispatch('SET_MENU_REQUEST', menuList)
  .run()
})
```

**update:**
I found some [documentation](http://redux-saga-test-plan.jeremyfairbank.com/unit-testing/saga-helpers.html) on how to utilize effect-helpers (takeEvery, takeLatest) and tried that too, but to no effect, it just causes a new error.

test with effect-helper:

```
it("Sets a new menu", () => {

  return expectSaga(menuSaga)
  .next()
  .put(setMenu(menuList))
  .takeEvery('SET_MENU_REQUEST', applyMenu)
  .finish()
  .isDone()
})
```

The error it throws:

```
 TypeError: (0 , _reduxSagaTestPlan.expectSaga)(...).next is not a function

      10 |
      11 |   return expectSaga(menuSaga)
    > 12 |   .next()
      13 |   .put(setMenu(menuList))
      14 |   .takeEvery('SET_MENU_REQUEST', applyMenu)
      15 |   .finish()
```

**The saga I am trying to test:**

```
import {fork, put, select, call} from 'redux-saga/effects'
import {takeEvery, takeLatest} from 'redux-saga'
import { handleRequest } from './serverSaga'
import { setMenu } from '../reducers/menuReducer'


const POST_MENU_REQUEST = 'POST_MENU_REQUEST'
const GET_MENU_REQUEST = 'GET_MENU_REQUEST'
const SET_MENU_REQUEST = 'SET_MENU_REQUEST'

export function setMenuRequest(menu) {return {type: SET_MENU_REQUEST, menu}}
export function postMenuRequest(data) {return {type: POST_MENU_REQUEST, data}}
export function getMenuRequest() {return {type: GET_MENU_REQUEST}}


export function* applyMenu(menu) {
  yield put(setMenu(menu))
}


function* postNewMenu(data){
  yield call(handleRequest, '/admin/menu' ,'POST', data)
}


function* getMenu(){ 
  let response = yield call(handleRequest, "/admin/menu", "GET")

  if(response){
    yield put(setMenu(response))
  }
}

export default function* menuSaga(){
  yield [
    fork(function*() {
      yield takeEvery(POST_MENU_REQUEST, postNewMenu)
    }),
    fork(function*() {
      yield takeEvery(GET_MENU_REQUEST, getMenu)
    }),
    fork(function*(){
      yield takeEvery(SET_MENU_REQUEST, applyMenu)
    })
  ]
}
```

As you can see I have tried to export the generator-function that I want to test, even though I don't think this is optimal since the test shouldn't require me to change my code just to test it, so I'm probably missing something.

The stub menuList has a structure like this:

```
Date: '', 
Id: '', 
ClosingTime: '',
MenuItems: [],
```

It's proving to be not-so-straigthforward to test my sagas since they are all structured like this one (forked) and there doesn't seem to be a lot of documentation as to how to test them properly.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, your problem is that you are importing and using *expectSaga* from redux-saga-test-plan when it should be *testSaga*

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your are mixing redux-saga-test-plan's unit tests with their integration tests.

```
expectSaga(menuSaga) // this is an integration test function
    .next() // this is a unit test function
    .put(setMenu(menuList))
    .takeEvery('SET_MENU_REQUEST', applyMenu)
    .finish()
```

see: https://redux-saga-test-plan.jeremyfairbank.com/integration-testing/